# Explain the output of the following C++ program?

Tags: c++, variables

```
int x = 10,y = 18; char z = '*';
cin>> x >> y >> z;
cout<< x << " " << y << " " << z << endl
```

Given the inputs "46" "A" and "49" in that order, the output when i run the program is "460*" (excluding quotations. Why is this so?

Comment: If you put the input into a condition (as in `if (cin >> x >> y >> z)`) you will notice that it *fails*. Think about how the letter `A` could ever be parsed as a decimal number (as expected when reading the input for `y`).

Comment: [Why does cin, expecting an int, change the corresponding int variable to zero in case of invalid input?](//stackoverflow.com/a/32378969)

Comment: It's easy to explain the behavior of the program. The more important question is, what did you expect the program to do and why did you expect that?

Answer (score 9):

`x` and `y` are integer types. `z` is a `char`.

Given the inputs `46` `A` `49`,

1. `cin>> x` succeeds and sets `x` to `46`.
2. `cin>> y` fails because `A` is not an integer. `y` is set to `0` and `cin` failbit is set.
3. Because `cin` is in failed status, `cin>> z` does nothing and `z` remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Your input fails at typing 'A' when an integer expected. It doesn't convert it into its ascii code automatically. That's the reason, why your last variable stays the same.
The second variable will be set to zero in such case.